# GNU Make: Exporting a Simply Expanded Variable

Tags: c, export, gnu-make

Following is a simplified version of the problem I'm having:

main.mk:

```
export lst :=

tmp := a
lst += $(tmp)
$(warning lst is $(lst))

tmp := b
lst += $(tmp)
$(warning lst is $(lst))

all:
        $(MAKE) -f sub.mk
```

sub.mk:

```
tmp := c
lst += $(tmp)
$(warning lst is $(lst))

tmp := d
lst += $(tmp)
$(warning lst is $(lst))
```

Running make -f main.mk prints the following:

```
main.mk:7: lst is  a
main.mk:11: lst is  a b
make -f sub.mk
sub.mk:4: lst is  a b c
sub.mk:8: lst is  a b d d
```

I defined lst as a simply expanded variable in main.mk, why has make converted it to a recursively expanded variable in the submake?

I read the following:

https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC59
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html

Neither states that a variable loses its "flavor" when exportd to a submake.

I am able to easily fix this by adding this to sub.mk:

```
lst := $(lst)
```

Seems like a hack though. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using GNU Make v4.1 in Cygwin, I also confirmed this behavior in Linux with GNU Make v3.81.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a consequence of this bit from the manual

> To pass down, or export, a variable, make adds the variable and its value to the environment for running each line of the recipe. The sub-make, in turn, uses the environment to initialize its table of variable values. See Variables from the Environment.

which is in the [Communicating Variables to a Sub-make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html) section you linked to in your post.

Specifically that there isn't a way (via the environment) to indicate which variables are recursively expanded and which are simply expanded. (Not without some other marking mechanism.)

Contrast this to

> make automatically passes down variable values that were defined on the command line, by putting them in the MAKEFLAGS variable.

and the fact that that variable (or `MAKEOVERRIDES` or the `-*-command-variables-*-` variable as the case may be) can actually contain the `=`/`:=` denoting the flavor.

Comment: I see your point, make uses the system's environment to export variables and this information is lost in the environment. Seems like this fact should be explicitly stated along with the default flavor that will be used. I confirmed that using := on the command line did preserve the flavor, but I wasn't able to accumulate the lst variable, it gets reset on every sub-make invocation. That's a different use case though, thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: I agree that this could probably be more explicitly stated. You accumulated `lst` values with `override` in the makefile and the sub-make passed value was the original command-line value? Because without `override` make assignments won't touch command-line assigned variable. But I would expect that with `override lst += c`, etc. you would get the modified value passed down to sub-makes.

Comment: Yes, I removed the export lst, and added override in front of every lst += statement. I read these articles: gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html, gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html, and gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html, and they don't explicitly state the behavior. I checked MAKEOVERRIDES in both files and it is always equal to the command line value (confirmed in Cygwin make v4.1 and Linux make v3.81). I could probably fix up MAKEOVERRIDES manually to get the expected behavior, or pass lst:=$(lst) to sub-makes.

Comment: Can you look at https://gist.github.com/deryni/3615cc5f03760abecf51 and try that and see what you get? You can see what I get there.

Comment: I get the same output, in all cases lst is not accumulated.

Comment: Hm? Yes it is. `sub.mk:11: lst is foo c d:simple` or did I misunderstand something. Oh? Did you mean `override` assignment in `main.mk` carrying through? I didn't test that.

Comment: Yeah, somehow I missed that when writing my test up. I'll have to test that in a bit.

Comment: It's not an issue for me anymore. Now that I understand the problem it's very simple to fix.

Comment: Hm... yeah, putting `override` in `main.mk` doesn't seem to work... That does seem like something that should be possible (though not required). But I can see how that would be complicated.